# Получить список категорий в которых лежат товары

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Подскажите, как мне получить список категорий в которых лежат товары, т.е. исключить пустые категории.

```
class ItemModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('categories.CategoryModel', related_name='item_category', ...)

class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```